# How to convert an atypical completion handler to Swift Concurrency

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I have in my code some asynchronous method written with a completion handler, and I want to convert it to the new Swift Concurrency syntax.

Usually this is simply a matter of wrapping the call in `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` and calling either `resume(throwing:)` or `resume(returning:)` instead of, respectively `completion(nil, error)` or `completion(value, nil)`.

However I have in my code a method that may call the completion handler with a value AND an error (the use case is: outdated cache, but use the value if network is unreachable), aka `completion(value, CacheError.outdatedCache)`.

What approach may I use to convert this to a *throwing async* method?

Comment: can you please create a short example (e.g. in Playground) demonstrating this problem?

Comment: A Swift function can either return a value or throw an error. It cannot do both. So what do you expect a `throwing async` method to do when the completion handler would return both an error and a value? If you want to return both a value and an error, return a tuple containing both or create a custom type that can contain both a value and an error.

Comment: `resume(throwing: CacheError.outdatedCache)` on cache error.

Comment: @cora - if that error is thrown, how will the cached value be retrieved?

Comment: @Rob Associated value :)

Comment: Yep, I went down that road, but you’d probably want to make that associated value be generic, which is hard to specialize in the `catch` statement. I guess you could have it not be generic, but then you end up having to define a unique error for every type of possible cached response.

Comment: Yes I was also thinking of an associated value, but thought it might not be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

There are many alternatives. Here are a few:

1. You could have a non-throwing rendition that returns a `Response`:

   ```swift
   enum Response<Value, Failure: Error> {
       case success(Value)
       case failure(Failure)
       case failureWithCachedValue(Failure, Value)
   }
   ```
2. You could have non-throwing rendition that returns a tuple of `(Foo?, Error?)`.

Comment: In the end as I refactored my code I ended up doing your option #1.